# Can xor of distinct prime numbers be 0?

Tags: math, primes, xor, bitwise-xor

I have tried this exercise for a few sets e.g. {2, 3, 5}, {5, 11} where xor of elements is not 0. My intuition suggests that it will always be non-zero but I am unable to prove it. I searched on the net but didn't find anything. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: With _two_ numbers, `xor` of them can only be zero if the numbers are equal (so nondistinct). With three numbers, one of them `2`, I see examples, like `{ 2, 5, 7 }`. This question may be better for [Math Stack Exchanges](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: xor is distribuyive. x xor 0 = x for all x. x xor x = 0 for all x. So if p xor q = 0 then p = p xor 0 = p xor (p xor q) = (p xor p) xor q = 0 xor q = q

Comment: for example, {5,7,41,43}

Comment: @MBo You should turn that into answer ...

Comment: As you can see its possible the idea behind is that each binary bit/digit must have even  number of `1` ones in all the xor'ed primes together. so find 2 big enough primes with relatively equal magnitude (so the MSBs cancel each other) and then just look for smaller primes that cancel out the resulting bits...

Comment: @Spektre Too little for an answer

Comment: The smallest counter example without `2` seems to be `{3, 5, 17, 23}` (many twin primes together with `2` form a triplet `xor`-ing to 0 when they are of the form `4k+1` and `4k+3`)

Comment: @JohanC: depending on your definition of "smallest", how about `{3, 5, 11, 13}`?

Comment: There's a wealth of examples here: if you give me *any* set of 9 distinct primes smaller than 256, then there will be some nonempty subset whose `xor` is zero. Similarly if you give me *any* set of 17 distinct primes smaller than 65536, or any set of `n + 1` or more distinct primes smaller than `2^n`. Finding the subset amounts to finding the kernel of a matrix over GF(2).

Comment: @MarkDickinson That is good. The smallest `n` for which your examples work (enough prime can be given) is `n=3`, so numbers with at most three bits. Here we need to come up with four primes under `8`, and it is possible: `2, 3, 5, 7`. So by your argument some nonempty subset works, and indeed that leads to the example of my first comment above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Condensed from comments to your question:

For two distinct primes, bit-wise XOR will not be zero. In general, XOR of two numbers is zero if and only if the two numbers are equal.

For three distinct primes, from considering the least significant bit only, we see that not all three primes can be odd numbers. But there exists only one even prime, namely `2`. Then the remaining primes, both odd, must be identical on every bit *except* the second-least significant bit where they must be different. They are therefore twin primes of the form `4k+1` and `4k+3` (note that twin primes of the form `4k-1` and `4k+1` do not satisfy the requirement). So the solutions for three primes are `{ 2, 5, 7 }; { 2, 17, 19 }; { 2, 29, 31 }; { 2, 41, 43 }; ...`.

For four primes, there are simply so many ways it can happen. From a simple program listing all occurrences with all primes under `50`, I get: `{ 3, 5, 11, 13 }; { 5, 7, 17, 19 }; { 3, 5, 17, 23 }; { 11, 13, 17, 23 }; { 3, 7, 19, 23 }; { 7, 11, 17, 29 }; { 5, 11, 19, 29 }; { 3, 13, 19, 29 }; { 7, 13, 23, 29 }; { 5, 11, 17, 31 }; { 3, 13, 17, 31 }; { 7, 11, 19, 31 }; { 3, 11, 23, 31 }; { 5, 13, 23, 31 }; { 5, 7, 29, 31 }; { 17, 19, 29, 31 }; { 7, 11, 37, 41 }; { 17, 29, 37, 41 }; { 19, 31, 37, 41 }; { 5, 11, 37, 43 }; { 3, 13, 37, 43 }; { 19, 29, 37, 43 }; { 17, 31, 37, 43 }; { 5, 7, 41, 43 }; { 17, 19, 41, 43 }; { 29, 31, 41, 43 }; { 7, 13, 37, 47 }; { 23, 29, 37, 47 }; { 3, 5, 41, 47 }; { 11, 13, 41, 47 }; { 17, 23, 41, 47 }; { 3, 7, 43, 47 }; { 19, 23, 43, 47 }; ...`.

For five primes, again not all can be odd, so one has to be `2`. But there are still a lot of ways it can happen (based on brute force search).

Not sure if this helps your intuition.